# Facebook Graph API - get comment URL from comment ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm using on my website the Facebook plugin for comments in pages/posts:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/?locale=en_US

**I want to get the URL where the comment was made using the comment ID.**

If you try the Facebook Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) you can get some information through a comment ID. Try, for example, the id:
10150381629441807_10156516790371807

You'll get:

```
    {
      "created_time": "2018-03-26T17:04:00+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "Zohar Sabari",
        "id": "10152863986513871"
      },
      "message": "great, thanks",
      "id": "10150381629441807_10156516790371807"
    }
```

So, does anyone know how to get the comment URL from comment ID?

Comment: Guess you could grab it from the `permalink_url` field. That seems to point to Facebook’s “link shim” script `https://l.facebook.com/l.php` most of the time, and the `u` parameter seems to contain the actual URL the comment is associated with.

Comment: What are you talking about? @CBroe

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150381629441807_10156516790371807%3Ffields%3Dpermalink_url&version=v2.12

Comment: @CBroe you solved my problem, thanks. If you don't mind, can you tell how did you come up with the field 'permalink_url'?

Comment: Really just using Graph API Explorer for exploring :-)